# How to check `system-type` over `tramp`?

Tags: tramp, system-environment

`system-type` work perfectly in local machine. How do I check `system-type` when connecting to a remote server over tramp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system-type` does not exist for remote machines. However, Tramp caches the result of `uname -sr` for every remote machine, a string. You can retrieve it by

```
(when (file-remote-p default-directory)
  (tramp-get-connection-property
   (tramp-dissect-file-name default-directory) "uname" nil))
```